# Laravel file storage architecture

Tags: laravel, file-upload, version-control

I have a laravel applications where users can upload files. Currently the files are stored in the storage directory.

However every time I re-deploy the application from version control I have to copy the files to a temp directory outside of the application, deploy the application and then copy them back into the storage directory otherwise they get deleted with each fresh deployment.

1. Is there a way to prevent each deployment overwriting the existing storage directory or
2. Is it best to store the files on a cloud storage system such as S3 instead?

Any pro tips, advice appreciated

Comment: 1. I usually have storage in my git-ignore.  2. Cloud storage all the way!

Comment: Usually the storage folder is symlinked to a directory outside of the project. Then you only have to have the symlink itself in version control.

Comment: @PtrTon so which folder should i be uploading into, is it directory outside of project which is symlinked to storage or the other way round?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you will use deployer from https://deployer.org for deploying application to production or to development server, then you can set up shared directiories by command:

> set(
> 'shared_dirs',
> [
> 'path/to/your/directiory',
> ]
> );

this directory will not be overwritten after deploy.

2. For using S3 its need to install via composer

   league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ~1.0

and set up config in config/filesystems.php

> 's3' => [
> 'driver' => 's3',
> 'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
> 'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
> 'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
> 'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
> 'credentials' => [ env('AWS_KEY'), env('AWS_SECRET')],
> 'acl' => 'public'
> ],

then add AWS credentials to S3 in .env file:

> FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=s3
> AWS_KEY=YOUR_KEY
> AWS_SECRET=YOUR_SECRET
> AWS_REGION=eu-west-1
> AWS_BUCKET=your_bucket_name
> AWS_ENDPOINT=https://your_bucket_name.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/

After this you can work with s3 Storage as if you are working with local Storage.